# When I inject email addresses into my webpage the '@' character is not displayed

Tags: php, html, include

I am injecting Email addresses using PHP into a web-page containing HTML. When I inspect element on the page the Email address is shown as Email: Bob@Bob.com, but the actual display on the page is Bob Bob.com, does anyone know the problem? I am using an imported font, if that is relevant.

Comment: chances are your font doesn't have an @ character

Comment: I'm sorry, can you edit with more details please? We need code and font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your external font doesn't contain the `@` character, you can change the font for the very `@` character only.
Say, `Bob<span style="font-family:sans-serif">@</span>Bob.com` which will result in displaying `@` anyways, but in Arial or whatever default sans-serif font is in your browser.

I would not say this is a PHP question though. Pure HTML/CSS

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't know if it was a problem with the php or the HTML/CSS